# VBA Getting Value From HTML

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to get the value from this html source code:

```html
K<sub>C</sub> [ksi&#8730in]:<br>
<input class="test1" type="text" name="fKC" value="">
<br>
```

and here is the code that I used but doesn't work:

```css
Sub test1()

Dim IE As Object

'=========Load Page
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "\\gsrv03\FDT_FractureToughness.html"
Do While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy = True
    DoEvents
Loop

'========Submitting Job
Set submit = IE.document.getElementById("isubmit")
submit.FireEvent "onclick"

Dim kfc As String
kfc = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("test1").innerText

MsgBox kfc

End Sub
```

Running the code above I got anerror message Run-time error '438'. Can someone please help?

Thanks,

Comment: What line are you having an issue on?

Comment: What is the expected output for the provided HTML sample?

Comment: IvenBach, the line that caused problem is "kfc = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("test1").innerText"

Comment: omegastripes, the expected output value is associated to the kfc name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure a more elegant solution will come along, but this should do the trick. Place the code below in place of kfc = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("test1").innerText

> ```
>     Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
>     For Each oHTML_Element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
>         If oHTML_Element.ClassName = "test1" Then
>             kfc = oHTML_Element.Value
>         End If
>     Next
> ```

Also, as tvu pointed out, you need a do while ie.readystate loop after the onclick fireevent and beware of empty values, maybe by setting kfc to an empty string first.

Good luck!

Comment: This actually spit out a value. It works good.  Thank you very much.